# sublime en-large and bold the bracket,single/double quote ...etc

Tags: sublimetext3

anyone know how to change Sublime 3 {} [] () '' "" ..etc
to bold + en-large when u focus on the bracket

for example, sublime set the font size to 12 and if the cursor is on/insdie the
{} , it will change to bold and en-large the font size to 14

i tired BracketHighlighter, underline is not good, because variable,URL,function name,....many things also has underline, just make more confuse

the best way is just bold and en-large the bracket a bit large than the default size, so can anyone know how to change this ?
Thx

Comment: Sublime uses the same font and font size for everything displayed in a single file, so there's no way to have different font sizes for different text within the same file.

Comment: oh too bad, thx for the answer